# If we have four grounded nodes in a circuit, can we connect two of them together and forget that those two were grounds?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ground, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: circuit]

Refer to the image attached. I personally think the answer is no because it is not necessary for the currents through both the grounded capacitors to be the same in the upper circuit, but that is not the case for the bottom one.

Comment: The two do not communicate the same schematic to me.

Comment: Join them together and ground, fine, But **forget** to ground at all... No...

Comment: @SolarMike Would this have worked if there were only two ground nodes?

Comment: Which two would you be thinking off? You should check to see if it is still equivalent...

Comment: @SolarMike If, say, there were no power supplies. Only two capacitor ground nodes. Then we could should be able to connect them together because in that case, the only information the grounding would provide is that the two nodes are connected.

Comment: If there are no power sources, what would you analyse...

Comment: Clearly, the 2nd circuit is not the same as the first as there's no option for current to flow through the capacitors to ground. Also, removing the ground places those two capacitors in series with each other and then in parallel with R, so NO.

Comment: You need the shunted charge to be able to return to the energy source. Thus the GNDs are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I personally think the answer is no (...)

What you are thinking is correct. In order to have an equivalent circuit, you will need to connect **all** ground nodes together. Just 2 out of 4 will not work because you are changing **Kirchoff's Current Law** in the ground node, and so influencing the solution of the circuit.

Only if you *know* that it won't influence Kirchoff's Current Law, you can remove the ground reference. For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx8zcV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Due to symmetry reasons, you can already see by inspection that the middle voltage is *always* 0V, so the GND-connection is not really necessary.

But it is not a general property.

Comment: Suppose there are 4 ground nodes, out of which one of them, say, the fourth one is connected to the non-inverting terminal of an ideal op amp. Now, current will not flow throw this connection. So, will it be fine if I just connect the remaining three ground nodes, ignoring the fourth one.

Comment: For this to be true, the two voltages must be precisely the same value, and likewise the two resistors. This is only possible on paper. So the answer refers to the trivial case.

Comment: @ShashankKumar if you leave out the non-inverting terminal to ground connection, the circuit will contain a floating node and it will become *unsolvable*.

Comment: @Chu can you please explain what you mean with *trivial case*?

Comment: A solution that is of little interest. For example: \$\small y -9x=0\$ has the trivial solution: \$\small y=x=0\$.

Comment: @Chu I agree it may be easy to see and appear as *obvious* to most, but I disagree that it is of little interest. It is common to apply this equality for circuits with differential signals (transmission line termination of differential signals, differential amplifier AC analysis, etc.)

Comment: Your second circuit has current through each resistor and a current to ground through the central conductor. Simple check with superposition. How can you say it’s equivalent to the first circuit which has zero current everywhere? Also, the voltage at the junction of resistors in the first circuit is vi, not zero.

Comment: @Chu Then I guess something went wrong in your analysis. Using superposition: \$v_{mid} = \frac{v_i}{2} - \frac{v_i}{2} = 0\$ (perhaps you forgot to invert the sign?)